# undefined method 'dragonfly_accessor'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, dragonfly-gem

I am new to dragonfly and trying to go through the setup directions on the main documentation page for rails.  Not using Active Record.

My steps:

1) add to Gemfile

```
gem 'dragonfly', "~>1.0.3"
```

2) `bundle install`

3) `rails g dragonfly`

created initializers/dragonfly.rb

4) model

```
class Post

  include Mongoid::Document

  dragonfly_accessor :image

  field :title, type: String

  field :body, type: String

end
```

5) controller

```
params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :image)
```

Just running mongod and rails s, I get the error of undefined method 'dragonfly_accessor'

Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? Where is it getting that error?

Comment: app/models/post.rb:6:in `<class:Post>'
app/models/post.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:10:in `index'

Comment: The documentation was not very clear, but I added "extend Dragonfly::Model" in my model for Post and the error is gone.  I found it under the dragon fly models documentation.

Comment: @user3295271 post your comment as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Also, the user’s error is that he’s not inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base.
Documentation is here.
(https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly)