# Dragonfly gem, image saving to DB but not appearing on page, "undefined method, 'dragonfly_accessor'" in Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, dragonfly-gem

This question [has been asked and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691261/undefined-method-dragonfly-accessor) (for that user), but my own experience has varied.

First: Rails 4.0.4, Ruby 2.1.0, Dragonfly gem 1.0.5.

I am using the Dragonfly gem for image uploads on this Rails 4 blog app and am experiencing an issue where the images appear to be saved through the model (locally, in the default public folder, at least: not yet using online file storage), but not appearing in the article show page. To be clear, the page loads and displays a broken image link.

Querying the specific article details in the Rails console gives me the following NoMethodError there:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `dragonfly_accessor' for #<Class:0x00000108bc17f0>
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing'
```

I've checked the gem is loading. The setup for Dragonfly is simply what's [provided on their site](http://markevans.github.io/dragonfly/rails/). I've generated the dragonfly.rb file inside the initializers folder. The following is my adaptation of the setup provided with the documentation:

(Model) article.rb:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

  dragonfly_accessor :image # Defines reader/writer for uploaded images
  # validators, etc...
```

Migration:

```
class AddImageToArticle < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :articles, :image_uid, :string
    add_column :articles, :image_name, :string
  end
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<%= image_tag @article.image.thumb('400x200#').url if @article.image_stored? %>
```

articles_helper.rb (where I keep my permissions for strong params):

```
module ArticlesHelper
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body, :tag_list, :image)
  end
end
```

Concerning the answer from the article linked at the top here, I've tried adding `extend Dragonfly::Model` to my article.rb model file; however, it results in `NameError: uninitialized constant Article::Dragonfly` when locating an article supposedly with uploaded images in the Rails console.

Have I missed any necessary details? Please let me know. Any assistance is appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add

```
def article_params
  params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body, :tag_list, :image)
end
```

in articles_controller instead of helpers.